# Failed to open LevelDB database [FSTFirestoreClient initializeWithUser:settings:] Firebase Swift Crash

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crash

**Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Failed to open DB: Internal: Failed to open LevelDB database**

Getting Crash once from every User its initialize the DB. Help Will Be Appreciated Thanks.

Comment: It seems you also opened an issue on Github for this, where it may be a better fit. Please follow up on the request for additional information that was left there. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3778

Answer (score 0):

**What helped me was to disable persistence. I started having the issue, when I started implementing Unit Tests. I assume, that the Tests created some kind of 2nd instance. Running for now without persistence, and will then figure out how to add it for production, but disable it for Unit Tests.**

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()

settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        
let firestore = Firestore.firestore()

firestore.settings = settings
```